# Sharepoint Metrics

Tags: sharepoint, website-metrics

I have a custom Sharepoint Page that pulls News and events into a feed on the page via REST API from sharepoint lists. How can I use these lists to store the amount of hits each news/event link gets?

I wanted to make a *timesClicked* field in each list, and increment it via POST every time a user clicks on it, but that would mean we have to give all users edit access to the news/event lists which we can't do. What other ways could I go about implementing a basic hit-counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a 2nd list that contains the following columns: item number of the first list and a counter. Set the security on the second list to allow edit from authenticated users. Use a POST to increment the corresponding row in the second list.